# Is having a long CSS selector bad?

Tags: css

Is a selector like

```
.a, .b, .c, .d, .e, .f, .g, .h, ......... , .zzzzz {font-size:16px}
```

bad for performance? If yes how and if no why?

I Googled and read a lot of posts including the ones by Mozilla and couldn't find any mention of having a large number of class names as a selector being bad.

Comment: If anything this is the best way of building your selector. Better than writing `{font-size:16px;}` serval times. Saves on bytes in the long run.

Comment: Agreed it saves on the bytes, but does it reduces browser's performance for parsing and applying the CSS?

Comment: Well yea the less bytes the browser has to read the better. The faster the page will load, no?

Comment: If you write them in one line, it is a big work to check whether comma or point are correct...

Comment: @benbai123 I uses SASS and its extend feature to generate this, its totally maintainable.

Comment: @Nitin, that's great, but in some chance might need to open it with some text editor elsewhere..., I mean, hope there is no such chance :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no performance problem here.

What is bad is a long selector involving many checks but your selector is in fact a sequence of selectors, equivalent to

```
 .a {font-size:16px}
 .b {font-size:16px}
  ...
```

Selectors with just a class are among the most efficient ones.

There's no real problem, even if you probably should have less classes in order to manage your code more easily.

Comment: Managing code is the very reason I did this, coz I use SASS and its 'extend' feature. But this means that the number of class names in the selector will keep on increasing as I add more web pages to my website. Is there a limit on the number of class names in a selector or any performance impact due to a large number of class names?

Comment: What do you mean "large" ? I use less but even with less or sass it's crucial to make your mind about the classes instead of throwing new ones in your code each time you have a new object.

Comment: I have created 3 classes for the 3 different font types(in terms of font-size, color and line-height) I am using throughout my site. So whenever I need to apply a font size instead of declaring this in the class I extend the predefined class for the font type. This makes it easy to change the font size of the whole website by changing it at once place. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But what is strange is that you have so many classes in total. But it may depend on what you call "large" and of your site, I can't really judge...

Comment: Agreed large is a vague term, still nothing bad you see with the selector right?

Comment: No, the selector is fine. Selecting by class is very efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the conversation, you rock \m/

Answer (score 2):

This is the valid syntax for assigning a common properties to multiple classes at a time. there is no down side effect.

Answer (score 2):

Saving a single bite is good. Yup as @dystroy said it's doesn't impact that much on your page performance but it's not a good coding particle & also it's hard to manage your code.

Write like this:

```
body{font-size:16px}
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting to code without spaces? Writing readable code is much, much more important. You can have a post-processor minify your css for you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't choose a large selector, you just assigned many selectors to your stylesheet. A large selector would be for example:

```
header nav ul li a
```

As the browser uses selectors from right to left the key-selector (the last selector in line, in this example the anchor-element a) is too general. When beginning to render the style the browser begins to grab for all elements according to the key-selector, what would probably mean, that it got much more elements, as effectively needed. In this example it would be much better, if navigation items get unique classes, so the stylesheet must only be applied to following selector:

```
.primary-link
```

So, it's import the right key-selector for your styles, to reduce the rendering time to a minimum.

If you want to read something interesting about CSS selectors and performance I can recommend that page: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/performance-organization